# Writing a custom IUserPasswordStore and SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync in Identity 2.1

Tags: asp.net-identity-2

Building a custom `IUserPasswordStore` to connect to a legacy system's username/password table. The password is hashed with custom code in the table so I need to write custom code for `PasswordSignInAsync`.

Do I need to override `PasswordSignInAsync` or is there a method I can provide that just does the hashing of the password? If I do override the entire `PasswordSignInAsync` is there sample code somewhere showing me what needs to be done in the method?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That was easier than I thought.

Override `CheckPasswordAsync` in `UserManager`.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who wants to see the complete setup in `.NET 6`, this is how it looks like:

### Step 1:

Add `CustomUserManager` to override `CheckPasswordAsync`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

public class CustomUserManager<TUser> : UserManager<TUser> where TUser : IdentityUser
{
    public CustomUserManager(IUserStore<TUser> store, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
        IPasswordHasher<TUser> passwordHasher, IEnumerable<IUserValidator<TUser>> userValidators,
        IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<TUser>> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer,
        IdentityErrorDescriber errors, IServiceProvider services, ILogger<UserManager<TUser>> logger)
        : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer,
              errors, services, logger)
    {
    }

    // THIS IS ONLY CALLED FOR USERS STORED IN YOUR IDENTITY DATABASE
    public override Task<bool> CheckPasswordAsync(TUser user, string password)
    {
        // Add custom check using user.UserName and password
        return Task.FromResult(true); // Replace this with your custom check
    }
}
```

### Step 2:

Register it in your `Program.cs`

```
builder.Services
.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
})
.AddUserManager<CustomUserManager<ApplicationUser>>()  <----- THIS GUY
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

`ApplicationUser` and `ApplicationDbContext` look like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

### Step 3:

Try to Login using this:

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync("SomeUserNameInYourIdentityDatabase", "SomePassword", isPersistent: true, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```