# Build a custom user check password in Asp.Net Identity 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

I need to build a custom user password check in an application implemented in asp.net MVC 5 and using Asp.Net Identity 2.

I read in a stackoverflow post ([Writing a custom IUserPasswordStore and SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync in Identity 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27789015/writing-a-custom-iuserpasswordstore-and-signinmanager-passwordsigninasync-in-ide)) that I only need to override the CheckPasswordAsync method in UserManager.

I try to override this method in IdentityConfig.cs file. Here is the code that I add to the ApplicationUserManager class just for test this solution:

```
public override async Task<bool> CheckPasswordAsync(ApplicationUser user,   string password)
{
        return await Task.Run(() => {
            return true;
        });
}
```

The problem is that this code is never run in the login process, and the login always fail. To sign in the user I’m using the SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync to log in the user, this is the default when creating a new web application in asp.net MVC 5. Shouldn’t this method call the ApplicationUserManager. CheckPasswordAsync? Or there is another configuration needed to this work?

Comment: Are you following the [Introduction to ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity) guide to trigger the authentication process? If not, how are you doing it? You need to explain it in your question.

Comment: I really not follow any configuration process. I just created an empty web application and tried to change the check password process. I will follow your suggestion to see if my custom check password works.

Comment: @Albireo I read the guide Introduction to ASP.NET Identity and I understood that I can change the Login controller in order to use my custom user check password method. But my question maintains. If I override the ApplicationUserManager.CheckPasswordAsync it shouldn't be called when I invoke the SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync method?

Comment: My question was only to try to narrow down your case: there's probably something missing or wrong somewhere else (as [LeftyX said](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31566074/91696), it *should* work), but without seeing the whole code is difficult to tell.

Comment: Are you calling the method manually when a user explicitly visits a page, or are you using OWIN to handle unauthenticated users that hit an [Authorize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx)'d action?

Comment: I already find out the problem @Albireo. I was trying to login with a non existent user. It seams that SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync never invoke the ApplicationUserManager.CheckPasswordAsync if the user not exists in the user store repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to login with a user that do not exists in the system.

The SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync never invoke the ApplicationUserManager. CheckPasswordAsync if the user not exists in the user store repository.

In conclusion, I have to store the users in my application or implement a custom user store mechanism.

Answer (score 8):

It should work. I've just used the standard ASP.NET MVC template, updated all the libraries involved through NuGet, and it must work.

I guess the problems is the way you are overriding the method.

In your `ApplicationUserManager` try to change your code like this:

```
public override Task<bool> CheckPasswordAsync(ApplicationUser user, string password)
{
    return Task.FromResult<bool>(true);
}
```

or:

```
public override Task<bool> CheckPasswordAsync(ApplicationUser user, string password)
{
    return Task.Run(() => MyCheckPasswordAsync());
}

private bool MyCheckPasswordAsync()
{
    return true;
}
```

and you will see it goes through:

[image]

Comment: What is exactly the online template that you use? I just find a template with the name ASP.NET_MVC5_Bootstrap3_3_1_LESS but it seams that the generated code is not exactly what you use. In this example in the controller login it use the  UserManager.FindAsyncn method and not the SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync method.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected my answer. I meant used the standard Asp.Net MVC Template. From Visual Studio 2013 - New Project Web - ASP.NET Web Application - MVC; Authentication = Individual User Accounts.

Comment: For an example for .NET 6, check out this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74707470/8644294

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a direct answer however it provides a full solution to the problem. He implements a custom authorisation filter which you can then customise to do what you want.

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Apr/18/A-WebAPI-Basic-Authentication-Authorization-Filter

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class BasicAuthenticationFilter : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
```

It can then be used like this instead of the [Authorize] attribute

```
[MyBasicAuthenticationFilter]
public class QueueController : ApiController
```