# Identity 2.0 with webservice username and pw verify

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I am updating an old forms application to MVC but can't figure out how to make meet the applications requirements using Identity 2.0. We have a single sign-on web service that manages user authentication. Basically, I pass a function the username and password and it returns true or false. All the user profile data is stored in the applications database. I can't seem to find anyone doing anything close to this. Im still searching but hoping that someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Never fails... right when you take the time to ask, you find the answer

[Build a custom user check password in Asp.Net Identity 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31559088/build-a-custom-user-check-password-in-asp-net-identity-2)