# MVC Owin Identity 2 CheckPasswordAsync() will not execute

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, owin

I have got 2 problems which seems to be related to each others and none of other duplicates in stackoverflow was answer to my question.

**First** when the `PasswordSignInAsync` method execute it will never stop or throw any exception it just continue executing :

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

**Second** I want to authenticate user by calling a web service which receives username and password and return user information so I override `checkPasswordAsync` method but it will never be executed :

```
 public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
       //...

        public override async Task<bool> CheckPasswordAsync(ApplicationUser user, string password)
        {
            return await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                return (checkUsernameAndPassword(user.username,password));
            });
        }
    //...
    }
```

Comment: Try using this: `await SignInManager.SignInAsync(model.UserName, true, true);` Does it at least finish?

Comment: Have you double checked against the username?

Comment: `ApplicationUser signedUser = UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email);` and then `var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(signedUser.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);`

Comment: @Codexer SignInAsync does finish but  does not do anything.
With your second solution the problem still remains.

Comment: Interesting, try this out. `var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
               
            }`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue.

It was because `CheckPasswordAsync` method never gets called for users not in your store (Identity database).

Try it with user in your table and you should be able to hit that method.

---

For someone who wants to see the complete setup, this is how it looks like:

### Step 1:

Add `CustomUserManager`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

public class CustomUserManager<TUser> : UserManager<TUser> where TUser : IdentityUser
{
    public CustomUserManager(IUserStore<TUser> store, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
        IPasswordHasher<TUser> passwordHasher, IEnumerable<IUserValidator<TUser>> userValidators,
        IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<TUser>> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer,
        IdentityErrorDescriber errors, IServiceProvider services, ILogger<UserManager<TUser>> logger)
        : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer,
              errors, services, logger)
    {
    }

    // THIS IS ONLY CALLED FOR USERS STORED IN YOUR IDENTITY DATABASE
    public override Task<bool> CheckPasswordAsync(TUser user, string password)
    {
        // Add custom check using user.UserName and password
        return Task.FromResult(true); // Replace this with your custom check
    }
}
```

### Step 2:

Register it in your `Program.cs`

```
builder.Services
.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
})
.AddUserManager<CustomUserManager<ApplicationUser>>()  <----- THIS GUY
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

`ApplicationUser` and `ApplicationDbContext` look like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

### Step 3:

Try to Login using this:

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync("SomeUserNameInYourIdentityDatabase", "SomePassword", isPersistent: true, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```

And you can be sure that you'll hit `CheckPasswordAsync` method.